# io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for whereas any() is used as an argument

Tags: kotlin, mockk

Currently, I'm working on unit tests and I'm using Mockk for that purpose.

Here's how my unit test looks like (I'll put the most important lines)

```
@Test
fun `Test computeDowntimesOverPeriod with starting uptime`() {
   every {incidentRepository.incidentsBySiteKey(any(), any(), or(ofType(String::class), isNull()))} returns buildIncidentsStream(5)

   mockSAT123Mapping()

   val timeIntervals = incidentManager.computeDowntimesOverPeriod("SAT.123", Period.ofWeeks(1))

   //...

   verify(exactly=1) {incidentRepository.incidentsBySiteKey(Period.ofDays(7),15, "asc")}
}
```

Here's the signature of the *incidentsBySiteKey* function

```
fun incidentsBySiteKey(period: Period, siteId: Int?, order: String = "asc"): Stream<Incident>
```

For the *computeDowntimesOverPeriod* function

```
open fun computeDowntimesOverPeriod(siteKey: String, period: Period): List<StatusTimeInterval> {
   //...
   val downtimes = incidentsBySiteKeyStream(siteKey, period)
   //...
}
```

The *incidentsBySiteKeyStream* function :

```
private fun incidentsBySiteKeyStream(siteKey: String, period: Period, order: String = "asc"): Optional<Stream<Incident>> {
   Objects.requireNonNull(period)
   return if (StringUtils.isEmpty(siteKey)) {
      Optional.of(Stream.empty())
   } else siteMapper.fromCMMSKey(siteKey)
      .flatMap { it.toUtId() }
      .map { siteId -> incidentRepository.incidentsBySiteKey(period, siteId, order).filter { equipmentRepository.findById(it.equipmentId).get().weight > 0 } }

}
```

As you can see, in the *computeDowntimesOverPeriod* function, we use the *incidentsBySiteKey* function. So, in the test it's logical to check whether or not the function is called. But when I run the test, I get the following error :

```
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: IncidentRepository(incidentRepository#28).incidentsBySiteKey(P7D, 15, asc)
```

So basically, my test failed when I initialized the *timeIntervals* variable. But why ? I mean, I have the every block that should return something for any argument.

Edit : kotlin version => 1.3.31
       mockk version => 1.8.13.kotlin13

Comment: How are you instantiating the mockk? Have you tried a relaxed mockk? i.e. incidentRepository = mockk<IncidentRepository>(relaxed = true)